# Retrieve data on many tables - Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel-5, eloquent, many-to-many, relationship

Good morning, 
Here is my model :

A **Chretien** can have many **Poste**. A **Poste** can belog to many **Chretien**. 
A **Poste** belongs to many **Departement**. A **Departement** has many **Poste**.

CHRETIEN------------------------POSTE---------------------------DEPARTEMENT
[image]
        0..*                0..*     1..**                 0.. *

How can I retrieve the model like this?

```
                         John DOE
        ---------------------------------------
        |**Postes**       | **Departements**  |
        ---------------------------------------
        |Pianist          | Musical Group     |
        ---------------------------------------
        | Secretary Curch | council           |
        ---------------------------------------
        |Wedding Planer   | Organizatin Comite|
```

Comment: Hello, in that box I do not understand what you want to get in the query, please edit your question and put in the form of code as you want to get

Comment: According to the model, if i want to retrieve all the postes of a user, i will do @foreach($chretien->postes as $postes) {{$postes->nom}} @foreach. I will have the list of the postes. But if i want the specific departement for each poste, what will ne the query?

Answer (score 0):

When accessing Eloquent relationships as properties, the relationship data is "lazy loaded". This means the relationship data is not actually loaded until you first access the property. However, Eloquent can "eager load" relationships at the time you query the parent model. Eager loading alleviates the N + 1 query problem. To illustrate the N + 1 query problem, consider a Chretien model that is related to Poste:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Poste extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the chretien that wrote the poste.
     */
    public function chretien()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Chretien');
    }
}
```

Now, let's retrieve all chretiens and their postes:

```
$chretiens = App\Chretien::with('postes')->get();

foreach ($chretiens as $chretien) {
    echo $chretien->postes->name;
}
```

For this operation, only two queries will be executed:

```
select * from chretiens 

select * from postes where id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...)
```

**Nested Eager Loading**

To eager load nested relationships, you may use "dot" syntax. For example, let's eager load all of the poste's and all of the departament's in one Eloquent statement:

```
$chretiens = App\Chretien::with('postes.departaments')->get();
```